# Unable to start Neo4j WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper when deployed as WAR

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception, neo4j

I have a Grails application running Neo4j as an embedded graph, and want to run the server application.  The application runs ok on my local machine using run-app, as well as using run-war, but when I deploy the application as a WAR file under Tomcat, I get the following null pointer exception.  Can anyone please advise?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.initializeContext(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 29 more
2014-12-05 15:33:13,769 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.initializeContext(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-12-05 15:33:13,770 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    ... 5 more
2014-12-05 15:33:13,771 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    ... 5 more
2014-12-05 15:33:13,771 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-12-05 15:33:13,771 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    ... 5 more
2014-12-05 15:33:13,780 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    ... 5 more
2014-12-05 15:33:13,780 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-12-05 15:33:13,780 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:89)
    ... 5 more
```

The bean serverWrapper is defined in resources.groovy:

```
serverWrapper(org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper) { bean->
            bean.constructorArgs = [ref('graphDatabaseService')]
            bean.initMethod="start"
            bean.destroyMethod="stop"
```

Comment: Gotta love open source.  Here's what's failing:   https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/Bootstrapper.java#L130   It's related to your config for the server.  Now, I don't know how you'd go about doing this via grails, but your problem seems to be missing config information for the server on what port it should use.  I won't post this as an answer because I don't have an easy resolution for you, but that's where to look.

Comment: Thanks - the master branch says the NPE is apparently fixed, but it is only incorporated into version 2.2.0-M01.  I have to use 2.1.6 because of other dependencies, so I'm stuck.  The failing line is here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.1.6/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/Bootstrapper.java#L130, and so I guess either configurator or configuration() is null.  I'm not sure why my application works when run using grails run-app or run-war (using a Grails embedded Tomcat container), but not when deployed as a WAR.

Comment: Further details here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/3450#issuecomment-65914779  It appears to be a problem in creating the logger, and specifically with the use of ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(), here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.1.6/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/configuration/Config.java#L86